# What is the necessity of junction tables?

Tags: sql, join, junction-table

I have implemented the following ways of storing relational topology:

1.A general junction relation table:

> Table: Relation
>
> Columns: id parent_type parent_id parent_prop child_type child_id child_prop

On which joins are not generally capable of being executed against by most sql engines.

2.Relation specific junction tables

> Table: Class2Student
>
> Columns: id parent_id parent_prop child_id child_prop

On which joins are capable of being executed against.

3.Storing lists/string maps of related objects in a `text` field on both bidirectional objects.

> Class: Class
>
> Class properties: id name students
>
> Table columns: id name students_keys
>
> Rows: 1 "history" [{type:Basic_student,id:1},{type:Advanced_student,id:3}]

To enable joins by the sql engines, it would be possible to write a custom module which would be made even easier if the contents of students_keys was simply `[1,3]`, ie that a relation was to the explicit `Student` type.

The questions are the following in the context of:

I fail to see what the point of a junction table is. For example, I fail to see that any problems the following arguments for a junction table claim to relieve, actually exist:

- Inability to logically correctly save a bidirectional relations (eg
  there is no data orphaning in bidirectional relations or any
  relations with a `keys` field, because one recursively saves and one can enforce
  other operations (delete,update) quite easily)
- Inability to join effectively

I am not soliciting opinions on your personal opinions on best practices or any cult-like statements on normalization.

***The explicit question(s) are the following:***

1. What are the instances where one would want to query a junction table that is not provided by querying a owning object's `keys` field?
2. What are logical implementation problems in the context of computation provided by the sql engine where the junction table is preferable?
3. The only implementation difference with regards to a `junction table` vs a `keys` fields is the following:

When searching for a query of the following nature you would need to match against the `keys` field with either a custom indexing implementation or some other reasonable implementation:

> class_dao.search({students:advanced_student_3,name:"history"});
>
> search for Classes that have a particular student and name "history"

As opposed to searching the indexed columns of the junction table and then selecting the approriate Classes.

I have been unable to identify answers why a junction table is logically preferable for quite literally any reason. ***I am not claiming this is the case or do I have a religious preference one way or another as evidenced by the fact that I implemented multiple ways of achieving this.*** My problem is I do not know what they are.

Comment: so, you want to store denormalised data in a relational database?

Comment: I want to understand the functional point of a junction table in the context of the costs of computation, not necessarily the ambiguous term "relational database". I am not going to restate the entire context in which I want to understand the point because that would simply be restating the question.

Comment: TL;DR - how do you store N-N relations in database, esp when both sides of relations have hundreds of records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I see it, you have have several entities

```
CREATE TABLE StudentType
(
    Id Int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVarChar(50) 
);

INSERT StudentType VALUES
(
    (1, 'Basic'),
    (2, 'Advanced'),
    (3, 'SomeOtherCategory')
);

CREATE TABLE Student
(
    Id Int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVarChar(200),
    OtherAttributeCommonToAllStudents Int,
    Type Int,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Student_StudentType
        FOREIGN KEY (Type) REFERENCES StudentType(Id)
)

CREATE TABLE StudentAdvanced
(
    Id Int PRIMARY KEY,
    AdvancedOnlyAttribute Int,
    CONSTRIANT FK_StudentAdvanced_Student
        FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES Student(Id)
)

CREATE TABLE StudentSomeOtherCategory
(
    Id Int PRIMARY KEY,
    SomeOtherCategoryOnlyAttribute Int,
    CONSTRIANT FK_StudentSomeOtherCategory_Student
        FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES Student(Id)
)
```

1. Any attributes that are common to all students have columns on the `Student` table.
2. Types of student that have extra attributes are added to the `StudentType` table.
3. Each extra student type gets a `Student<TypeName>` table to store its specific attributes. These tables have an optional one-to-one relationship with `Student`.

I think that your "straw-man" junction table is a partial implementation of an EAV anti-pattern, the only time this is sensible, is when you can't know what attributes you need to model, i.e. your data will be entirely unstructured. When this is a real requirment, relational databases start to look less desirable. On those occasions consider a NOSQL/Document database alternative.

---

A junction table would be useful in the following scenario.

Say we add a Class entity to the model.

```
CREATE TABLE Class
(
    Id Int PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
)
```

Its concievable that we would like to store the many-to-many realtionship between students and classes.

```
CREATE TABLE Registration
(
    Id Int PRIMARY KEY,
    StudentId Int,
    ClassId Int,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Registration_Student
        FOREIGN KEY (StudentId) REFERENCES Student(Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Registration_Class
        FOREIGN KEY (ClassId) REFERENCES Class(Id)
)
```

This entity would be the right place to store attributes that relate specifically to a student's registration to a class, perhaps a completion flag for instance. Other data would naturally relate to this junction, pehaps a class specific attendance record or a grade history.

If you don't relate `Class` and `Student` in this way, how would you select both, all the students in a class, and all the classes a student reads. Performance wise, this is easily optimised by indices on key columns.

---

When a many-to-many realtionships exists without any attributes I agree that logically, the junction table needn't exist. However, in a relational database, junction tables are still a useful physical implmentaion, perhaps like this,

```
CREATE TABLE StudentClass
(
    StudentId Int,
    ClassId Int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_StudentClass PRIMARY KEY (ClassId, StudentId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Registration_Student
        FOREIGN KEY (StudentId) REFERENCES Student(Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Registration_Class
        FOREIGN KEY (ClassId) REFERENCES Class(Id)
)
```

this allows simple queries like

```
// students in a class?
SELECT StudentId
FROM StudentClass
WHERE ClassId = @classId

// classes read by a student?
SELECT ClassId
FROM StudentClass
WHERE StudentId = @studentId
```

additionaly, this enables a simple way to manage  the relationship, partially or completely from either aspect, that will be familar to relational database developers and sargeable by query optimisers.

Comment: The question isn't dealing with the Type of hierarchy of Student but rather the Class2Student relation. Take the simplest case to evaluate the efficacy of a junction table, the addition of the Student Type hierarchy was to illustrate the type of custom indexing necessary to implement #3. What are the advantages in the context of: [computation performance, functionality] offered by a junction table? Why would you use a junction table if it forces 2 joins vs 1 and doesn't provide any functionality?

Comment: @MetaChrome I hope my extended answer better answers your question.

Comment: The example of properties of a relation itself is valid and would require a junction/relation Entity.

Comment: `select * from class
join student where (student.id in class.student_keys)` in the context of a correctly saved bidirectional relationship one would be able to assign all of the classes of a student by nature of the fact that they are returned by the query (with an iteration of the Students after initializing the Classes). for a non bidirectional relation between 2 types... thinking about it. a nested join?

Comment: I suppose in general it is a question of how many nested joins you want to execute to suport a deep cascade in the general case. If you're not going to be doing deep cascades with joins, it may not matter (in the sense that you have decided to do multiple queries to facilitate deep cascades when a cache of objects isn't available)? However, in the instance of wanting to have such a custom query, I suppose it would be multiple queries or a nested recursive join.

Comment: @MetaChrome I've added more on the situation where no attributes exist.